# Leaflet map does not show up properly. Partially grey.

Tags: leaflet

I have tried my best to take solutions here from diverse answers but my problem remains. 
The map does not show up properly. A grey frame is taking almost 3/4 of the frame. 
[How the map shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gdtkj.png)

```
<div id="map"></div>

<script>

 var map = L.map('map',{scrollWheelZoom: false});
 map.setView(<%= @location.latlng %>, 16);
 marker = L.marker(<%= @location.latlng %>).addTo(map);
 L.tileLayer('http://a.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: 'Your attribution statement',
                      maxZoom: 20,
                      subdomains: '',
                      }).addTo(map)
$(document).ready(function(){
    L.Util.requestAnimFrame(map.invalidateSize,map,!1,map._container);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Data-toggle tab does not download Leaflet map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246815/data-toggle-tab-does-not-download-leaflet-map/36257493#36257493).

You probably need a longer delay before calling `map.invalidateSize()`. Ideally listen to the event that opens your map container to its correct size.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try out today!