# Phonegap plugin moves Leaflet map center

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2, leaflet, phonegap-plugins

I observed an interesting effect with Leaflet maps in my ionic2 app. Viewing the map, I run the [social share](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin) overlay, enter the text message input field and return to the map. Now, the map center has been moved from the view center to the upper left corner. The map is reloaded around the the upper left corner, leaving the whole view gray.

Is there a way to reset the link between my encapsulating div object and the map 
engine so that it would refresh at the center of the view again? I believe something is going wrong between handing back control from the native plugin to ionic2 and then the leaflet map.

Here's the simplified layout.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic2Leaflet
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div style="height: 100%;width:100%;">
    <div style="height: 100%;width:100%;" id="map"></div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Sounds like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246815/data-toggle-tab-does-not-download-leaflet-map

Comment: Wow, thanks for the link. That was quicker than I expected! Looking into this to fix it.