# Leaflet map not loading in Bulma tab using Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, tabs, leaflet, bulma, buefy

I have an issue with loading Leaflet map using Vue.js and Bulma tab components (via Buefy).

If map is placed inside tab then it does not load all tiles until browser window is resized.

If map is placed outside of Bulma tabs component then it loads without any issue.

Calling `map.invalidateSize()` seems to help, but to do it automatically when tab changes I have to call it using `setTimeout` and put very big delay, like 1sec - which is very ugly.

How to get this working without this `invalidateSize` workaround?

Example with the issue: https://codepen.io/alxxnder/pen/zyYxwd

Example without the issue: https://codepen.io/alxxnder/pen/LMYEjr

Code:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    map: null,
  },
  methods: {
    invalidateSize: function() {
      this.map.invalidateSize();
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.map = L.map('map').setView([38.63, -90.23], 12);
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(this.map);
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Leaflet Test</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/buefy@0.7/dist/buefy.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css">
</head>

<body>


  <div class="section">
    <div class="container" id="app">
      <b-tabs position="is-centered">
        <b-tab-item label="Tab 1">
          <div class="section">
            Tab 1
            <div class="map" id="map" style="height: 400px; width: 100%"></div>
            <button class="button is-info" @click="invalidateSize()">invalidateSize</button>
          </div>
        </b-tab-item>
        <b-tab-item label="Tab 2">
          <div class="section">
            Tab 2
          </div>
        </b-tab-item>
      </b-tabs>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/buefy@0.7/dist/buefy.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: And most important - why this happens at all?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246815/data-toggle-tab-does-not-download-leaflet-map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in [Data-toggle tab does not download Leaflet map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246815/data-toggle-tab-does-not-download-leaflet-map), the issue is caused by the fact that your map container does not have yet its full size when you initialize it. You may understand it more easily if your map had been in an initially hidden tab (e.g. in tab 2).

As for your initially active tab (i.e. tab 1), it is probable that Buefy / Bulma still takes some time to reveal the tab content.

Since there is no event when the tab transition completes, you have to wait for the transition duration before calling the [`invalidateSize`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#map-invalidatesize) method. In your case, 300ms seems to be fine.

Then you should also call it again when the user [changes the tab](https://buefy.github.io/documentation/tabs) (see Buefy tabs events), otherwise should the browser had changed size while your tab was hidden, the same issue would happen again.

Demo with maps in the 2 tabs:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    map: null,
    map2: null,
    tabMaps: []
  },
  methods: {
    invalidateSize: function(tabIndex) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (typeof tabIndex === "number") {
          this.tabMaps[tabIndex].invalidateSize();
        } else {
          // invalidate all maps
          this.tabMaps.forEach(map => {
            map.invalidateSize();
          });
        }
      }, 300);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.map = L.map('map').setView([38.63, -90.23], 12);
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(this.map);

    // map2 in tab2
    this.map2 = L.map(this.$refs.map2).setView([38.63, -90.23], 12);
    L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png").addTo(
      this.map2
    );

    this.tabMaps.push(this.map); // 0
    this.tabMaps.push(this.map2); // 1
    this.invalidateSize();
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/buefy@0.7/dist/buefy.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css">

<div class="section">
  <div class="container" id="app">
    <b-tabs @change="invalidateSize" position="is-centered">
      <b-tab-item label="Tab 1">
        <div class="section">
          Tab 1
          <div class="map" id="map" style="height: 400px; width: 100%"></div>
          <button class="button is-info" @click="invalidateSize()">invalidateSize</button>
        </div>
      </b-tab-item>
      <b-tab-item label="Tab 2">
        <div class="section">
          Tab 2
          <div class="map" ref="map2" style="height: 400px; width: 100%"></div>
        </div>
      </b-tab-item>
    </b-tabs>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/buefy@0.7/dist/buefy.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok, I got it working like I needed. If map is on second tab only then it is enough to add `<b-tabs @change="invalidateSize()">` event listener and call invalidateSize using small timeout `setTimeout(function(){ self.map.invalidateSize(); }, 10);`. Not sure why yesterday it worked with big delay only, but now it seems 10ms to be enough. Tried many times in different browsers.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I was trying your solution but couldn-t get it working even with a huge delay

Comment: @Hvitis: please feel free to open a new question with details of your specific issue.

Comment: I have EXACTLY the same problem. I will copy it here then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63315942/buefy-steps-and-tabs-block-leaflet-map