# Buefy steps and tabs block Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, bulma, buefy

I have an issue with loading Leaflet map using Vue.js and Bulma stepper components (via Buefy).

If map is placed inside stepper then it does not load all tiles until browser window is resized.

If map is placed outside of Bulma stepper component then it loads without any issue.

How to get this working ?

Example with the issue: https://codepen.io/alxxnder/pen/zyYxwd

Example without the issue: https://codepen.io/alxxnder/pen/LMYEjr

```
 <b-steps>
        <b-step-item label="Account" icon="account-key">
                        <LMap
                            style="height: 350px"
                            :zoom="zoom"
                            :center="center"
                            @click="adjustMarker"
                        >
                            <LTileLayer :url="url"></LTileLayer>
                            <LCircleMarker
                                :lat-lng="circle.center"
                                :radius="circle.radius"
                                :color="circle.color"
                            />
                        </LMap>
             </b-step-item>
        <b-step-item label="Profile" icon="account"></b-step-item> 
    </b-steps>
```

There is no difference if I load the map in tab 1 or tab 2.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when the Leaflet map is rendered, it doesn't know the size of its "viewport" (since it isn't visible in the DOM).

It does get rendered by Vue though, since Buefy's Steps-component uses `v-show` to show/hide each step instead of `v-if`.

To fix this, I've applied a somewhat hacky solution where I watch for changes to the active tab, and then invalidate the Leaflet map.

```html
<template>
  <b-steps v-model="activeStep">
    ...
  </b-steps>
</template>

<script>
export default {
...
watch: {
  activeStep() {
    if (this.map) {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.map.invalidateSize();
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```