# Leaflet map doesn't cover whole map area

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, maps, ionic4

**Update:** I have put my answer. Please see it.

**Original Question:**

Can you tell me why [leaflet map](https://leafletjs.com/) doesn't show on the full map area?

*.html*

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div style="height: 100%;width:100%" leaflet [leafletOptions]="options" *ngIf="options" [leafletCenter]="center">
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

*.ts*

```
  init(): void {
    this.options = {
      layers: [
        tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", { maxZoom: 18, attribution: "..." })
      ],
      zoom: 10,
      center: this.center = latLng(Number(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get("latitude")), Number(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get("longitude"))),
      attributionControl: false,
    };
  }
```

*UI*

[image]

Please see the image. It seems a problem with `transform`. Default it was `0,0,0`. I have changed it manually on the browser like so. So how can I set it to the map?

[image]

Comment: Most probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246815/data-toggle-tab-does-not-download-leaflet-map/36257493#36257493

Comment: @ghybs Please see my update and advice me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data-toggle tab does not download Leaflet map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246815/data-toggle-tab-does-not-download-leaflet-map)

Comment: @IvanSanchez It didn't work. This works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55622789/1077309

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I'm using this with `Ionic 4` app. I have tried many solutions given by different devs. But none of them worked for me. The problem here is the `life cycle` event which I have used earlier. So now I use `ionViewDidEnter()` and no issues.

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.center = latLng(Number(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get("latitude")), Number(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get("longitude")));
    this.options = {
      layers: [
        tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", { maxZoom: 18, attribution: "..." })
      ],
      zoom: 17,
      center: this.center,
      attributionControl: false,
    };

    this.layers.push(this.mapService.getMarker(this.center, "assets/icon/map/placeholder.png"));

  }
```

Comment: To be exact what you do here is delaying the map initialization through assigning your `options` member later, which governs the `*ngIf` of the map container with its `leaflet` directive in your template. Should you invalidate the map size instead in this lifecycle hook, the result should be the same.

Comment: @ghybs I have done that. But it didn't work for me. Maybe I have done it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in an ionic 4 project. Like suggested in comment with [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36257493/6294072) I needed to use `map.invalidateSize()` when I rendered the map, as well as when adding/removing markers or any other action for that matter. This didn't help completely. I also had to manually trigger change detection after that. Here's a sample from our code:

```
this.map.setView([this.myLocation.latitude, this.myLocation.longitude], 13);
this.map.invalidateSize();
this.ref.detectChanges();
```

where `ref` refers to `ChangeDetectorRef`.

Also make sure that you have the the leaflet css imported in your `angular.json` file:

```
"styles": [
  // ....
  "./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the leaflet is filled 100% in its parents space, can you use the browsers inspect tool to see what is the parents width and height. You can also try using

position: absolute; left: 0;

to ignore parents width

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the padding and changing height to 100vh

Try this:

```
<ion-content>
  <div style="height: 100vh; width:100%" leaflet [leafletOptions]="options" *ngIf="options" [leafletCenter]="center">
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

If you want to set the transform do it like so:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div style="height: 100%; width:100%; transform: translate3D(250px, 200px, 100px)" leaflet [leafletOptions]="options" *ngIf="options" [leafletCenter]="center">
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, even with the import of leaflet.css and the "invalidateSize()" trick.

It was because I wrote in "myComponent.page.html":

```
<ion-content>
  <div id="map" style="height:400px; width: 100%;"></div>
</ion-content>
```

It seems Ionic4 css conflicts with leaflet.
You need to get the `<div>` **outside of** `<ion-content>`.

Correct is just :

```
<div id="map" style="height:400px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Hope this help someone

Answer (score 0):

**map.invalidateSize()**  runs after window resize event.

So after height change, just write the code :

```
 window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
 this.map.invalidateSize();
```

It works like a charm in my case.
Dont' forget to replace **map**  with your map variable.
My it helps someone