# Vue-Leaflet map doesn't render completely

Tags: vue.js, leaflet

I have been following the vue2-leaflet [documentation](https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.app/quickstart/) and I have managed to render my map.

However , it only covers a portion of the entire frame.

I don't know what else to do in order to render it completely.

[image]

```html
<l-map
   ref="locationsMap"
   style="height: 300px"
   :zoom="zoom"
   :center="center"
>
    <l-tile-layer
       :url="url"
       :attribution="attribution"
    ></l-tile-layer>
    <l-marker :lat-lng="markerLatLng"></l-marker>
</l-map>
```

I have read something about using `invalidateSize();` in a similar issue ([Leaflet map doesn't cover whole map area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55617065/leaflet-map-doesnt-cover-whole-map-area)) but I don't see what the point is or how to use it.

Comment: Isn't this coming from the `height: 300px` part? Did you inspect the thing with your browser devtools?

Comment: Hi, I solved it running this function ```this.$refs.locationsMap.mapObject.invalidateSize();```. I am not sure what is exactly is causing the issue but this solves it