# leaflet fitbounds not working on seperate maps

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet, vuetify.js

I am desperately trying to solve this problem. I hope you can shed some light on it.

I have these components(`Parent1, Paren2, LeafletMap`).

`Parent1` includes `Parent2`  **4** times. `Parent2` includes `leafletMap`. So this means `leafletmap` component is rendered **4** times.

`Parent1` passes some data to `Parent2` and `Parent2` does some modifications and passes different kind of data for `leafletMap`.

Now, In `Parent1` component, where I include `Parent2`, I  have **4** tabs. IN each tab, I include the `Parent2` component.

Now, `Parent2` gets data as markers and I pass those markers to `Parent2`'s included component - `leafletmap`. `LeafletMap` component does this as soon as it gets the data.

```
let points, bounds;
      points = bounds = [];
      for(let i=0; i < this.markers.length; i++){
        if(!this.map.hasLayer(this.markers[i])){
          this.map.addLayer(this.markers[i]);
          let p = new L.latLng(this.markers[i].getLatLng().lat, this.markers[i].getLatLng().lng);
          points.push(p);
          this.oms.addMarker(this.markers[i])
        };
      }
      this.map.fitBounds([points]);
```

**Error-Question:** The thing is this fitbound works perfectly for the first tab and shows the map correctly with the correct zoom. but as soon as I change the tab, the map looks like the blue thing. I tried to console log map's zoom property after I made fitbounds, and for the first tab, it prints 10, and for all other tabs, it prints 0. Why is that?

I am using vue.js, vuetify for tabs and leaflet for maps.

Comment: Most probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246815/data-toggle-tab-does-not-download-leaflet-map

Comment: Difficult to answer without having the code. We could help you more if you  post your code in a jsfiddle or similar.