# React Leaflet Map won't proper render

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

Update: I couldn't solve the css issue. A friend recommended to me Mapbox and I have subsequently swaped the map. I'm so happy now.

Good evening community, my map appears only a bit. When I move the map by hand everything will be ok afterwards. I followed all instructions form https://react-leaflet.js.org/ and tried several solutions from the net, but can't solve it. Hope someone of you can give me the final hint, why I'm stuck.

[incomplete map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Clmah.jpg)

[image: complete map after resize]

```js
// 1. App.js
// 2. Body.js

// App.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Spinner from "react-bootstrap/Spinner";
import "./normalize.css";
import "./App.css";
import Body from "./components/Body";
import Card from "./components/Card"

function App() {
  const [geoPosition, setGeoPosition] = useState(null);
  const [extraCountryInfo, setExtraCountryInfo] = useState(null);
  const [spinnerEnabled, setSpinnerEnabled] = useState(false);
  const [myLocationData, setMyLocationData] = useState(null);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchLocationInfo = async () => {
      console.log("test");
      let getCurrentCountry = "";
      setSpinnerEnabled(true);
      try {
        const { REACT_APP_API_KEY } = process.env;
        const getMyLocation = await axios(
          `https://geo.ipify.org/api/v1?apiKey=${REACT_APP_API_KEY}`
        );
        getCurrentCountry = getMyLocation.data.location.country;
        setMyLocationData(getMyLocation);
        setGeoPosition(getMyLocation.data.location);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
      try {
        const getExtraCountryData = await axios(
          `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${getCurrentCountry}?fullText=true`
        );
        setExtraCountryInfo(getExtraCountryData);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
      setSpinnerEnabled(false);
    };
    fetchLocationInfo();
  }, []);

  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id="wrapper">
        {extraCountryInfo && myLocationData && (
          <Card
          extraCountryInfo={extraCountryInfo}
          myLocationData={myLocationData}
          geoPosition={geoPosition}
          setGeoPosition={setGeoPosition}
          ></Card>
        )}
        {spinnerEnabled && <Spinner animation="border" />}
        {geoPosition && <Body geoPosition={geoPosition} />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

//Body.js
import React from "react";
import { MapContainer,TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import './Body.css'


export default function Body(props) {
  // console.log(props)  
  return (
    <div id="mapid">
      <MapContainer
        center={[props.geoPosition.lat, props.geoPosition.lng]}
        zoom={13}
        scrollWheelZoom={true}
        >
        {console.log("re render",props.geoPosition.lat, props.geoPosition.lng)}
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={[props.geoPosition.lat, props.geoPosition.lng]}>
          <Popup>
          Your are here 
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
/* 1. App.css */
/* 2. Body.css */

/* App.css */
ul{
  list-style: none;
}

li{line-height: 1.5rem;}

.App {
  background-image: url("./assets/XT205511.JPG");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-Content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  background-color:lightblue;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 80%;
}

/* Body.css */
#mapid { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  /* width: 40rem;
  height: 20rem; */
    border: 2px rgb(241, 241, 243) solid;
    border-radius: 1%;
    margin-top: 0.5rem; 
  }
  
  .leaflet-container {
    /* width: 100%; */
    height: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
   crossorigin=""/>

    <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
```

Comment: Your code snippet is not testable but it sounds like a CSS issue. If there is existing props to pass classNames and styles in react-leaflet, use those. On the other hand if there isn't props built-in. You will have to use !important or find the css class names via chrome inspector to test and modify manually.

Comment: I recreated your scenario in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-question-rl-improper-render-6bi1c), but I am not able to reproduce your problem.  I agree this *may* be a CSS issue, but you are properly linking leaflet's css.  It looks like leaflet is having a hard time retrieving that one tile from OSM on the right side of the map.  The fact that the map looks correct after some panning makes me beleive this may be some strange network request issue for the specific tiles that are not showing up.  Does this happen if you try other `center` lat lngs?  What does your network tab say?

Comment: What happens if you resize your browser window?

Comment: Good morning, thank you all for your very fast reply :) . I just use the template from react-leftlet page. made no other fancy stuff. 
@Alex, I'll try your way, but it takes me a bit.

Comment: Good morning, thank you all for your very fast reply :) . 
@SethLutske , my code is a nested part, I'll update the snippet and add my app.js/css. I add also the network info.

Comment: Good morning@ghybs , after resize the map appears -> Opening dev tools and *boom* map appears fully.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246815/data-toggle-tab-does-not-download-leaflet-map/36257493#36257493

Comment: @ghybs thank you for the link. Unfortunately it doesn't work, maybe I've implement it wrong. Today I had help from a colleague and we tried similar approaches but even with no result. I'm still on it and if I find a solution, I'll let you know.