# Vue leaflet doesn't work when building app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet

I'm currently creating a vue3 cli app that uses [vue-leaflet](https://github.com/vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet) (the vue3 compatible version)

Everything works great on my local dev environment but once my app is built the map doesn't load, even when I resize like this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246815/data-toggle-tab-does-not-download-leaflet-map) explains well.

I tried using the `leafletObject.invalidateSize()` method but nothing changed.

My map is a component called using a v-if on first call (switch between a list view and the map) and a v-show once it has been initialized

```
  <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
    <Map v-if="mapInit"
         v-show="(!mobileView && !listing) ||
          (mobileView && !listing && !getFiltresMobile)"
         :liste="getFilteredList"/>
  </transition>
```

Here is what I get on my dev version when I use `npm run serve`
[image]

Here is the result on the prod version
[image: lealfet prod]

Here is the relevant part of my code, I can add more if you think more code needs to be shown

```
<template>

  <div id="map">
    <l-map v-if="!loading" :style="mapHeight" :zoom="zoom" :center="centerValue" :options="{tap : false}" ref="map">
      <l-tile-layer :url="url"></l-tile-layer>
      <l-marker v-for="(marqueur) in mapData" :key="marqueur.id" :visible="isFiltered(marqueur)" :lat-lng="marqueur.latLng" :ref="setMarkerRefs" @click="markerClick(marqueur.latLng)">
        <l-icon :icon-url="checkActive(marqueur.latLng)" :icon-size="[30 , 37]" :popup-anchor="popupUpPosition" :icon-anchor="[15, 37]"/>
        <l-popup :options="popupoptions">
          <MarqueurPopup :contenu="marqueur"/>
        </l-popup>
      </l-marker>
    </l-map>
    <Loader v-if="loading"/>
  </div>

</template>
```

JS

```
<script>
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"
import { LMap , LTileLayer , LPopup , LMarker , LIcon } from "@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet";

export default {
  name: "Map",
  props : ['liste'],
  components: {
    Loader,
    MarqueurPopup,
    LMap,
    LTileLayer,
    LMarker,
    LPopup,
    LIcon,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      url: 'https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png',
      zoom: 13,
      mapData : [],
      markerRefs : [],
      markerRefsDef : [],
      popupoptions : {
        maxWidth : 1000,
        minWidth : 300,
        closeButton : false,
      }
    };
  },

  beforeMount() {
    this.initMap()
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout( () => {
      console.log(this.$refs.map.leafletObject) // returns the leaflet map objects
      this.$refs.map.leafletObject.invalidateSize(); // no error but does nothing 
    }, 1000);
  },
  computed : {
    popupUpPosition() {
      if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
        return [0, 74]
      }
      return [0, -37]
    },
    mapHeight() {
      let colonneValue = window.innerWidth / 12;
      if (colonneValue < 115) {
        colonneValue = 115
      }
      let height = window.innerHeight - colonneValue;

      return {height : height+'px'}
    },
  },
  methods : {
    async initMap() {
      this.$store.commit('changeLoading' , true);
      this.mapData = []
      this.mapData = this.getFilteredList
      this.$store.commit('changeLoading' , false);
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Is there a way to check if the `invalidateSize()` methods triggers ? My console.log get no errors but nothing changes so maybe it doesn't trigger the method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather looks like the Leaflet CSS is incorrectly loaded in your production bundle: tiles are scrambled up, no zoom and attribution controls.