# React Leaflet map shows some extra blank space after collapsing MUI Drawer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm creating a React Js app using [MUI](https://mui.com/) as the core component and [React Leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/) as the map container.

There is some extra blank space (a UX issue) with the React Leaflet map after when the MUI `Drawer` is collapsed.

Here is the initial condition (the MUI `Drawer` component is expanded)
[image]

Here is the screenshot after clicking the collapse button for the MUI `Drawer` component from the MUI `AppBar` component (the extra blank space appears on the right of the screen)
[image]

Why does this happen and what is the solution for this issue?

Here is the code and the playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-leaflet-map-with-mui-drawer-9c6ner

Note:

1. I have to use `react-leaflet` v3 and `react` v17 dependencies because in my real project, I have to use `react-leaflet-markercluster` v3 dependency which is not supported yet with `react-leaflet` v4 and `react` v18
2. If this issue isn't reproducible in your browser, please try to enlarge your codesandbox browser and then try again.

Comment: The issue is not reproducible in this demo

Comment: hello @kboul it also happened to me first. but after I tried to enlarge the codesandbox browser, this issue was reproducible. Or you could try to downgrade the `react` and `react-leaflet` dependencies as I mentioned above.

Comment: Why don't you downgrade them directly in the sandbox so other users can see immediately the issue? Time is precious

Comment: @kboul you're right. okay I will do it soon. sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Smells like common invalidateSize case. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246815/data-toggle-tab-does-not-download-leaflet-map