when you click on the tab that was hidden, the leaflet map is not displayed properly
EDIT: This is solved per my answer posted below, thanks to comment by ghybs.
In my actual code which has multiple UI inputs that change the data displayed on the map (some of those UI elements being global, so you could change them in other parts of the site), I use leafletProxy to addMarkers. For me the final answer was an observer that called invalidateSize() per this code with 100ms delay, then after that (e.g. at least 100ms later) calling leafletProxy to fitBounds().
ORIGINAL POST: I created a shiny app with a page_navbar and multiple menu options. One option is 'Density map', basically leaflets with addCircleMarkers. I wanted to compare density maps across time periods, so I created a tabset containing two tabs, each with a leaflet displaying data for same species, different time period.
It works as expected when you click the Density map menu option and use the feature. But if you then click away to another main menu option, then click back to Density map -- when you click on the tab that was hidden when you clicked away, the leaflet map is not displayed properly. At minimum this looks like some degree of grey area with the map not centered.
This code allows you to reproduce something similar to what I am describing.
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(bslib)


ui <- tagList(
  page_navbar(
    id = "nav",
    
    title = "Leaflet Maps in Tabs",
    
    sidebar = sidebar(
      id = "global_sidebar",
      nav_panel("Placeholder")
    ),
    
    # Home tab
    nav_panel("Home",
              p("Welcome to the Home Page!")
    ),
    
    # Maps tab with tabset
    nav_panel("Maps",
              tabsetPanel(
                id = "map_tabs",
                tabPanel("Current",
                         leafletOutput("current_map")
                ),
                tabPanel("Previous",
                         leafletOutput("previous_map")
                )
              )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$current_map <- renderLeaflet({

    current_markers <- data.frame(
      lat = c(37.7749, 34.0522),
      lng = c(-122.4194, -118.2437)
    )
    
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(
        data = current_markers,
        lng = ~lng,
        lat = ~lat,
        popup = ~paste("Location:", lat, lng) 
      ) 
  })
  

  output$previous_map <- renderLeaflet({

    previous_markers <- data.frame(
      lat = c(40.7128, 42.3601),
      lng = c(-74.0060, -71.0589)
    )
    
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(
        data = previous_markers,
        lng = ~lng,
        lat = ~lat,
        popup = ~paste("Location:", lat, lng) 
      ) 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


If you run this code, then:

Click Maps and confirm both tabs are working
Toggle to hide the sidebar
Click Home
Toggle to show the sidebar
Click Maps
Click the tab for the other map that was hidden when you clicked away

You should see some degree of grey, you might be able to drag the map back into center, but if you go beyond bounds more grey will takeover and the map is unusable.
You can reproduce without using a sidebar toggle (and rewrite example without bslib and without a sidebar)

Click Maps and confirm both tabs are working
F12 to bring up dev tools
Click Home
F12 to hide dev tools
Click Maps
Click the tab for the other map that was hidden when you clicked away

My code is a lot different, notably I have css for the map height, I use leafletProxy and fitBounds, and in addition to addMarkers I use addCircleMarkers and addLegend. One other thing I have noticed in my actual code that may be relevant is: when the rendering issue occurs, the leaflet map always retains the legend and the markers, but the circlemarkers are always gone.
I am more of a tinkerer/hacker than a coder, this is for a volunteer project. I have tried to rewrite it many ways, this post is the simplest version of everything I have tried. The main thing I have tried is when it detect clicks on a tab, call my udpate_density_map() function which calls leafletProxy to update the map.
Should I reconsider trying to have a tabset of leaflets, or is there a fix for the issue I am experiencing?
Tested on Windows 11 23H2 using Chrome Version 130.0.6723.70 (Official Build) (64-bit) and Edge Version 130.0.2849.52 (Official build) (64-bit). R 4.4.1, leaflet 2.2.2, shiny 1.9.1
To give some context/colour to the post, a live development version of the site that I am actively rewriting is at https://insightful.kiwi/wkt-dev/

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246815/data-toggle-tab-does-not-download-leaflet-map

The answer for this question is per ghybs's reply and explanation here, my interpretation in a shiny context is as follows. I didn't see an option with the shiny leaflet library to call invalidateSize(), so using shinyjs.
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(bslib)
library(shinyjs)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- tagList(
    useShinyjs(),
    page_navbar(
        id = "nav",
        
        title = "Leaflet Maps in Tabs",
        
        sidebar = sidebar(
            id = "global_sidebar",
            nav_panel("Placeholder")
        ),
        
        # Home tab
        nav_panel("Home",
            p("Welcome to the Home Page!")
        ),
        
        # Maps tab with tabset
        nav_panel("Maps",
            value = "density_map",
            tabsetPanel(
                id = "map_tabs",
                tabPanel(
                    value = "current",
                    "Current",
                    leafletOutput("current_map")
                ),
                tabPanel(
                    value = "previous",
                    "Previous",
                    leafletOutput("previous_map")
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    current_markers <- data.frame(
        lat = c(37.7749, 34.0522),
        lng = c(-122.4194, -118.2437)
    )
    
    message("observeEvent rendering output$current_map")
    output$current_map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>%
            addTiles() %>%
            addMarkers(
                data = current_markers,
                lng = ~lng,
                lat = ~lat,
                popup = ~paste("Location:", lat, lng)
            )
    })
    
    previous_markers <- data.frame(
        lat = c(40.7128, 42.3601),
        lng = c(-74.0060, -71.0589)
    )
    
    message("observeEvent rendering output$previous_map")
    output$previous_map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>%
            addTiles() %>%
            addMarkers(
                data = previous_markers,
                lng = ~lng,
                lat = ~lat,
                popup = ~paste("Location:", lat, lng)
            )
    })
    
    
    observeEvent(input$map_tabs, {
        req(input$nav == "density_map")
        message("observeEvent detected change in tabs")
        
        selected_tab <- input$map_tabs
        
        if (selected_tab == "current") {
            shinyjs::runjs('setTimeout(function() { 
                var mapObj = HTMLWidgets.find("#current_map").getMap(); 
                mapObj.invalidateSize(); 
                console.log("invalidateSize() called on current_map");
            }, 100);')
        }
        
        if (selected_tab == "previous") {
            shinyjs::runjs('setTimeout(function() { 
                var mapObj = HTMLWidgets.find("#previous_map").getMap(); 
                mapObj.invalidateSize(); 
                console.log("invalidateSize() called on previous_map");
            }, 100);')
        }
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

This may not be the best way, feel free to post corrected or optimized versions.

Thanks for this - I was having the same problem but didn't know what was causing it! I found mapObj.invalidateSize(); didn't work but mapObj.resize(); does, despite there still being a console error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resize')
